# C# EndOfStream always true - Seek/Position to 0 not works

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stream, inputstream, sharpziplib

I want to detect the encoding of a XML document before parsing it. So I found on stack**overflow** this script.

```
public static XElement GetXMLFromStream(Stream uploadStream)
{
    /** Remember position */
    var position = uploadStream.Position;

    /** Get encoding */
    var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(uploadStream);
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();

    /** Move to remembered position */
    uploadStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin); // with "pos" = 0 it not works, too
    uploadStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Current); // if I remove this I have the same issue!

    /** Read content with detected encoding */
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(uploadStream, xmlReader.Encoding);
    var streamReaderString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return XElement.Parse(streamReaderString);
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Always I get `EndOfStream` **true**. But it isn't!!!! -.-

For example I have the string `<test></test>`.
Begin: 0, End: 13

If I `ReadToEnd` or `MoveToContent` then the end is reached successfully. The `EndOfStream` is **true** then.

If I reset the position via `Seek` or `Position` to 0 (for example) then a `new StreamReader` shows always `EndOfStream` is **true**.

The thing is that the `uploadStream` is a stream which I can not close.

It's a *SharpZipLib* stream of a http upload stream. So I can't close this stream. I can only working with it.

And the bad thing is only because `Position` and `Seek` not work... Only because `ReadToEnd` relays on this `Position`. - Else it would work. I think!

Maybe you can help my with this situation **:-)**

Thank you very much in Advance!

**Example:**
[image: Example of <code>EndOfStream</code> is true - but the Position is not at the end!]

Comment: The zip stream surely obfuscates the problem.  A network stream does not support seeking and if you read bytes from it then they are irretrievably lost.  Unless you buffer them yourself with a MemoryStream.  That can take a lot of memory, you may have to write it to a temp file.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is fundamentally incompatible with some types of input streams. Streams are not required to support `Seek` at all. In fact, `Stream` has a property specifically to detect whether `Seek` is usable, called [`CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Code needs to take into account that `Seek` can fail.

The simple but not very memory-efficient way is to copy your stream's content into a `MemoryStream`. That one does support `Seek`, and you can then do whatever you want with it. The fact that you're using `ReadToEnd()` suggests that the data is not so large that the memory use is going to cause a problem, so you can probably just go with this.

<sup>Note: as documented, if `Seek` is not supported, it's supposed to throw a `NotSupportedException`. It looks like with the stream implementation you're dealing with, it's not supported, but not properly implemented. I hope at least that `CanSeek` returns `false` for you, so you can still reliably detect this.</sup>

Comment: `CanSeek` is in all cases true. And I got no exception. That's why I ask you here. Maybe it's a bug with *SharpZipLib*?

Comment: @Patrick Yeah, that's what I was worried about and why I included my note. That does look like a bug in the implementation, but the workaround is the same: copy everything to a `MemoryStream` and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @hvd I found out the same and et voilà - it work's!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

XElement has a [Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method that will read directly from an xml stream. It will manange the encoding for you internally. And it'll be more efficient by avoid a needless string.  So why not use this.

```
XElement.Load(uploadStream);
```

Option 2:

If you really want to work with a string, dont use **new XmlTextReader()**. The XmlTextReader.Create() has more features so do this instead:

```
var xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(uploadStream);
var streamReaderString = xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();
return XElement.Parse(streamReaderString);
```

Comment: Good call, the OP does state "I want to detect the encoding of a XML document before parsing it." but doesn't explain why and doesn't use the encoding except for parsing.